# That/if difference in indirect questions

Tags: subordinate-clauses, interrogatives

> I asked him **if** I might see his watch?

So can I write this above sentence like this?

> I asked him **that** could I see his watch?

What if I use "that" instead of if?

Comment: When you use _that_ you need to use indirect speech. But you used a direct speech in your sentence. That aside you have a yes/no question to include indirectly which doesn't work with _that_. You need to use _if_ or _whether_. _That_ is used with quoting sentences as in _he told me that he could stay here for 2 years_. As opposed to _he asked if he could stay here for 2 years_ which is from _can I stay here for 2 years_.

Comment: Neither of those should have a question mark, because they are not questions.  They're simply statements: I asked him if _____.  You would only use a question mark if you're quoting a question: *I asked him, "Can I see your watch?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use 'that' instead of 'if', because this is a reported *question of the yes/no type* using Indirect speech, and the form **'ask' + 'if / whether' + clause** must be used. For example,

> He asked me if I spoke English.

or

> He asked me whether I was British or American.

So, if you're looking for an alternative to 'if', I suggest you use 'whether', adding an 'or not' after 'watch' (as 'whether' is used when there are two options), but 'that' is not correct.

[Here](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/question-forms-and-reported-speech/) are more examples for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not a question of whether it uses indirect speech: "He told me that he was English" uses indirect speech, and is fine. It's the (unpredictable) property of _ask_ that it takes an _if_ (or _whether_) clause but not a _that_ clause (except in the different sense of "request": _He asked that we clear up when we had finished._)

Comment: I expressed myself wrong saying 'a question using indirect speech': what I meant was a reported yes/no question using indirect speech. Thanks for taking notice. Will edit.

Comment: Compare *Did I know **that** he was guilty?* and *Did I know **if** he was guilty?* The first version has an embedded *statement* (which pragmatically is often implied to be *true,* a "given"), where the second has an embedded *question* (which pragmatically would usually be implied to be still unresolved).

Comment: if I was to report those questions were asked to me, I would say "I was asked if/whether i knew that/if he was guilty". If/whether are still the only correct alternatives to report the question on your example: what you say makes perfect sense, but I fail to see how whether the content of the question includes an 'if' or a 'that' or not is relevant.

Comment: @Matias, I think FumbleFingers was giving an example (_know_) where both _if_ clauses and _that_ clauses are allowed, but have different meanings. _Ask_ only takes _if_ clauses (except in the different sense I mentiojned).